What syntax do I need to make the compiler put this variable on the stack?
I'm decompiling an old game that was ported to the PlayStation 2. The game was shipped as a debug build, and as a result has DWARF v1 debug data. The compiler used is Metrowerks CodeWarrior.
There's one function that's giving me trouble in matching it with the original assembly:
void sibi2() {
  short block_no, i;
  short* block_tbl;
  short* tbl[3] = { tate, yoko, naname };

  if (actwk[0].mstno.b.h == 43 || actwk[0].r_no0 >= 4
      || plpower_a != 0 || plpower_m != 0
      || ((short*)&actwk[0])[26] != 0 || st6clrchg == 0)
    return;

  block_tbl = tbl[st6clrchg - 1];
  block_no = scramapad(&actwk[0], actwk[0].xposi.w.h, actwk[0].yposi.w.h);
  block_no &= 2047;
  i = 0;
  while (block_tbl[i] >= 0) {
    if (block_no == block_tbl[i++]) {
      playdamageset(&actwk[0], &actwk[0]); break;
    }
  }
}

In the original assembly, the local variable block_tbl is located on the stack, right next to tbl. This was confirmed using the internal debugger of PCSX2, a PlayStation 2 emulator. However, when I compile this code, block_tbl is put in CPU register s0.
I've tried various variable placements and small code changes, but the only thing that made the compiler put the variable on the stack is to change its type from short* to short*[1]. However, this also causes the type in the debug data to change, so this is not what was originally written.
Does anyone have any idea what the code needs to look like? To make things easier, there's a decomp.me scratch where I've been trying to match the assembly.

Related (or dup): How to insist a C compiler put local variables on the stack, not in registers

Why do you need it to be on the stack?

@n.m.couldbeanAI this is decompilation, where the goal is to derive source code that compiles to a specific sequence of assembly code. The OPs goal is likely to end up with source code that can perfectly reconstruct the target ROM. Some recent examples include perfect_dark and sm64.

Somewhat surprisingly, declaring block_tbl as short *volatile block_tbl seems to work fine (https://decomp.me/scratch/jU2yO - 99.69% match). The logic here is to make the pointer itself volatile, inhibiting some of the compiler assumptions that could otherwise cause it to store the variable in a register.
Note that I have not checked whether this affects the debug data; in principle, DWARF can represent the volatile modifier but not all compilers will actually output the volatile tag. It’s also probably not what was originally written by the developers, since it doesn’t seem to make much sense to make that particular variable volatile.

Another, somewhat simpler approach is just to take the address of block_tbl, which forces it to have a stack address. Since you’re compiling without optimizations, even a statement like (void)&block_tbl; is sufficient to force the compiler to use a stack variable (demo: https://decomp.me/scratch/fyAUr, also 99.69%). This has the advantage of not changing the type of the variable at all.

The problem with this approach is that it blocks optimizations of block_tbl. The version I posted would similarly force the variable onto the stack but otherwise not block optimizations.

In this particular application, whether it blocks optimizations or not actually does not matter, because the goal is to match a specific assembly output using a specific compiler. My addendum also addresses the issue by avoiding volatile entirely, and just forcing the use of a stack variable.

(void)&block_tbl; is a no-op and will just get optimized out if optimizations are enabled. Codewarrior in particular is a bit of an oddball, often you cannot quite turn off optimizations completely. I'm not familiar with the OP's particular port however.

Yes, it's a no-op. It works in this case, because we're dealing with an old compiler with optimizations turned off. For a modern compiler with optimizations, you'd have to try a slightly different trick; I don't claim my approach generalizes. But it works for the OP's problem.

Microcontroller flavours of Codewarrior won't allow you to turn optimizations completely off - there's some basic optimization layer present at all times. If you'd for example do stuff like void f (int x) { int y = x; printf("%d", y); } then it can decide to never allocate y no matter how hard you try to disable optimizations. But in this case I guess it's all about trying and see what you end up with.

Adding volatile does not change the debug info in this case, so it's a valid option, but I agree that it's probably not what was originally written. A related function (sibi) with the same local variable has it put in a register. It's more likely that the variable's address was taken somehow, so I'll need to think of where and how that might have been done.

@user16316067 I just checked and it's possible that the address computation is done inside a block of dead code (example: https://decomp.me/scratch/p6Nww). It could, for example, be debugging code that has been removed by defining a constant to zero. Therefore, it may not be possible to make a perfect guess as to how the address got taken.

How to deal with local automatic variables is not normally under developer control.  This depends on the ABI and the optimization rules used by the compiler, and mangling with it produces severe alterations in program structure and code speed (even if you succeed in having equivalent code).  IMHO, the best approach is to compile the code, produce assembler code, then tweak the assembler code in order to fit a place in the stack for the mentioned variable.
How code efficiency will be altered?  Well, of course having a local variable in a register has many efficiency benefits, as no external memory is needed to access the variable.  If that variable has been located in a cpu register this means that its use will be very short timed, and also be used many times inside the function to justify that a register is better solution to avoid bus accesses to get the variable contents.  Think that a local variable ceases to exist once the function it belongs to is finished, so a register is the better place to put it on.  The only limitation for this approach is that the number of registers is limited by the architecture. And that many times, the compiler needs to make a decistion in order to estimate which variables can be in registers and which have to be in memory.
Another question is why do you want the variable to be in the stack.  Is there any requirement to enfoce it to be in memory.  If the compiler has decided that variable is to be put on a cpu register, why do you think it will be better to put it on stack memory?
A solution to that is.... just print the variable address.  Then the compiler will need (even if it is not to use it) the memory address and this will enforce the use of a memory place to put the variable on.  This, again cannot enforce actually the compiler to use the in-memory value, but just to copy the variable value from the register to the memory address if you pass the variable by reference to an unknown function (a function compiled in a different compilation unit) that requires the compiler to pass it well updated.
Something like:
    int variable;
    ...
    dumb(&variable);  /* here, even if the compiler has assigned a
                       * register for variable, the pointer passed to
                       * dumb() must be a memory location, and it
                       * will have the actual value of variable, if
                       * the compiler cannot make an assumption from
                       * how dumb() has been compiled (you don't need
                       * to do anything to the passed pointer, just
                       * to ensure that dumb() will not be compiled in
                       * the same compilation unit as the one holding
                       * variable */

Here, until the call to dumb() and after it, the compiler can be using a register for variable.... but for the call to dumb() to be valid, just before calling it, there must be a local variable (in the stack) to hold variable's value, and after the call the value will need to be restored from memory to continue using it in a cpu register.  But if you ask the compiler to optimize your code, the compiler is free to maintain the variable in a register.
You can also declare the variable as volatile to indicate that it can be changed externally, and the cached value in a register cannot be used for calculations.  But this is, again, compiler dependant (e.g. it cannot work if you declare your variable static if the compiler detects the variable is never accessed out of the execution thread)

As the very first phrase of the question plainly states, this is a decompilation. Matching the original assembly is the entire point!

Compiling is a process in which, depending on how it is done, a lot of information is lost (more if you optimize compilation)  If you are decompiling, why to ask on compilation making locals to be in the stack?  Please, be concrete in your question, and you will receive precise answers.  If, on the other side, you know the answers to your question, why to ask it at all?  You know how to decompile... well, then you are right :)

The question is concrete. But you don't seem to understand it because you keep asking a question that's already answered in the question and in several comments.

The answer was also given to your question in my answer.  There's no official syntax in the C standard to enforce local variables to stay in the stack.  Indeed in the standard there's no such concept as the stack.  I agree in that I have also told you a lot of reasons that can lead to the code you detect in your second program.  But 1) I don't have your development environment 2) I cannot reproduce or see the assembly listings you talk about in your question and 3) You provide no real code in your question.  Then It's normal I can misunderstan part of your question. ... (continues)

(continued) ... My apologies for that.  Do you prefer I erase my answer or instead you think I'm trying to mesh you?  In any case, my apologies are sincere. Thank you for your feedback, anyway.

You've indeed tried to answer my question, but other answers have already provided the same information. That being said, what do you mean, no real code? I've provided the C code, and I've provided a link to a decomp.me scratch where you can see the expected assembly and play around with the C code, which is being compiled on the fly so you can see the resulting assembly and compare it to the original. There's no need for a development environment.

Yes, you are right, and my apologies for that, but you are required to provide a Minimal, complete and reproducible example, not something that requires to download, and build a complete application.  The reason is that we provide help on a voluntary basis,  so you are required to work the minimum example that fails.  I normally provide the help I can, not always looking at what has already been answered, as this makes me to lose time sometimes.  Being unthankful is not the way to get good answers, but I cannot help you on that.

Your sample code is far from Reproducible and is incomplete. :)

You can do something like this:
short* block_tbl;
short*volatile* = &block_tbl;

Another option would be something like:
#pragma DATA_SEG my_memory
short* block_tbl
#pragma DATA_SEG DEFAULT

where my_memory is a custom segment in your linker script.

Your first suggestion does not work. With volatile, it fails to compile (https://decomp.me/scratch/IGQkY - illegal conversion from short ** to volatile short **); without volatile, the match is only 95.28% (https://decomp.me/scratch/t46nu), compared to the 99.69% in my answer.

@nneonneo Oops my bad, see changes.

Okay, that at least compiles, but it's still 95.28%. The dummy variable results in an actual computation in the assembly (addiu   s2,sp,0x4c) because we're compiling without optimizations.

@nneonneo Yeah there's no way to avoid the pointer assignment to get executed with or without optimizations. But that kind of micro-optimization is kind of silly.

@nneonneo, what is the meaning of that 95.28%.

It’s the match score, as displayed on decomp.me (see the links in my answer and in the question). In decompilation, the goal is to match a target bit of assembly code; the performance of the code isn’t relevant because you know exactly what assembly code you want to output. The purpose is to get source code that you can compile into a specific ROM or artifact. Optimizing, improving or porting the code can come after you’ve proven it matches the original.

The compiler may optimize local variables away into CPU registers. Here, block_tbl is assigned a value once, and later only used to perform memory lookups. The compiler most likely recognized that its more efficient to just keep this value in a register for the entire scope of the function, rather than putting it on the stack which would require reading and writing to system memory (which is orders of magnitude slower than keeping it in a register). Since the variable is used continuously to access memory locations in a loop, it would have to be loaded into a register anyways, and since the value doesn't change the compiler can just decide to keep it there.
As to how to force this variable being located on the stack: this is most likely dependent on the compiler you're using. If your compiler allows to configure optimization settings you can most likely find it there. I don't know enough about the Metroworks Codewarriors compiler you mentioned to say which setting it is exactly. Disabling optimizations altogether, and creating a Debug build will probably have the same effect, but performance may be degraded significantly.
short*[1] is a different type than short*. short* is a pointer value, whereas short*[1] is an array of pointers, which in C is equivalent to a pointer to an array of pointers, or in C syntax short**

Isn't this just a re-statement of the problem?

I noticed that too, I added a comment about compiler flags that can toggle certain optimizations. I don't think theres a way to achieve this purely from within C, it is most likely gonna have to be a compiler specific solution. Either via flags or via preprocessor directives taylored to a specific compiler.

If the compiler in question supports preprocessor statements like in this answer, then you could wrap this single function with the pragmas to achieve the desired effect

This game was shipped as a debug build, meaning it was compiled with all optimisations turned off. I also compile with all optimisations off.
